# Download Image from backend rest api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, express

I have written a REST API in express which returns image Url in JSON like this `{image: urlData}`. I want to download that image on react front end. I have created a button after clicking that button I want to download that image with image name. How can I achieve this??

Comment: This question is to broad to answer in detail, but maybe https://blog.logrocket.com/programmatic-file-downloads-in-the-browser-9a5186298d5c/ helps. In summary, you could create an anchor, set the download attribute (HTML5) and trigger the download (e.g., via click). But again without more details, what should happen when and what you tried so far it's hard to help.

Comment: thanks for the help this will solve my problem.